# Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec Executing only first line

Tags: java, python

I want to execute a python script from java.
The code is getting in to the python file but only executes first line of the file.

following is the code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python "+dir+"/pyfiles/testfile.py");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        value = in.readLine();
```

after the first line nothing is executed.
what is the solution?

'dir' value is getting from

```
final String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

link to python file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tvkFTM_Oo5gTS7FyzeNgoeY5DLitFQjD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Try reading all the lines from the `BufferedReader` .

Comment: is your python file expects arguments to be sent while executing `python file.py`? if it then sends it from Java.

Comment: yes.it does.send it from java means?

Comment: now aim passing like this :

Comment: Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python "+dir+"/pyfiles/getGitFiles.py "+ownerVal+" "+repoVal+" "+folderVal+" "+branchVal+" "+Values.accessToken );

Comment: for my case it executes till `inside script file
at BEGIN
at END
('1', '2', '3', '4', '5')`, because there is some issue with executing some other methods. is it fine?

Comment: when i'am running only 'inside script file' is showing in console..nothing else is executed

Comment: which java and python version?

Comment: java 1,8 python 2.7 .thanks for the reply guys..finally got the answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems, that you are only reading the first line of your `BufferedReader`. So change your code as follows:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python "+dir+"/pyfiles/testfile.py");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
     System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: this worked for a test file which had 3 print statements..iam attaching the link to my file

Comment: for this file only first line is printed

Comment: Can you attach the python file in your question? Thanks.

Comment: python file is attached

Comment: The script which I attached is working fine.i tested it seperately

Answer (score 0):

it worked fine when I passed like this:

```
String cmd = "python2.7 "+dir+"/pyfiles/getGitFiles.py "+ownerVal+" "+repoVal+" "+folderVal+" "+branchVal+" "+Values.accessToken;
System.out.println(cmd);
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

passing the arguments inside the 'exec' itself is causing the problem.